# AndroidTestCase get file from resource folder

Tags: android, android-testing

The structure of my project is:

```
src
--main
----java
----res
--test
----java
----resources
```

How can I access file from resources folder from AndroidTestCase?

Comment: getActivity().getResources()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt").getFile();
```